# JavaScript how do i iterate over every current and future element in a HTMLcollection?

Tags: javascript, loops, htmlcollection

> An HTMLCollection in the HTML DOM is live; it is automatically updated when the underlying document is changed.

im trying to write a simple script, for a website that often adds elements, that recolors those elements based on criteria.

now, i dont want to have a loop continusly running and checking for new elements, for performance reasons.

how would i use a live HTMLcollectio nand execute a function on every element in it, even the new ones added?

if i can accomplish this, it should result in a script that never finishes, and recolors all new elements.

any help appreciated!

Comment: That's not how it works. You save the collection in a global variable, and whenever you loop over it, it will contain the current DOM elements. But nothing automatically executes the loop whenever the collection changes.

Comment: This is a prime example of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - the real issue you want to solve is something like "change any elements that match criteria even if they are added later", yet you are asking for how to iterate over an HTMLCollection. If you can focus on the core of your problem, you can find better alternatives. Off the top of my head, it seems like a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) could fit better.

Comment: @vlaz

ohhh, that makes sense. and yeh ive seen the answer that suggests a mutationobeserver and i hope i can figure out how to make this work. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver) to accomplish this task. It will watch a node for changes, and if needed it will watch the subtree for changes as well (which I don't think is needed here). As nodes get added, we can send the node to a function to apply some feature on it. In the example below we just randomly select a color and set the background.

```js
let targetNode = document.getElementById('watch')

// Apply feature on the node
function colorNode(node) {
  let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
  let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
  let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
  node.style.background = `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`
}

// Watch the node for changes (you can watch the subTree if needed)
let observerOptions = {
  childList: true
}

// Create the callback for when the mutation gets triggered
let observer = new MutationObserver(mutationList => {
  // Loop over the mutations
  mutationList.forEach(mutation => {
    // For added nodes apply the color function
    mutation.addedNodes.forEach(node => {
      colorNode(node)
    })
  })
})

// Start watching the target with the configuration
observer.observe(targetNode, observerOptions)

/////////////////
/// Testing
/////////////////
// Apply the inital color
Array.from(targetNode.children).forEach(child => colorNode(child))

// Create nodes on an interval for testing
setInterval(() => {
  let newNode = document.createElement('div')
  // Some random text
  newNode.textContent = (Math.random() * 1000).toString(32)
  targetNode.appendChild(newNode)
}, 2000)
```

```html
<div id="watch">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
</div>
```